# why do printf in C need to specify type of data

Tags: c

i wonder why we need to specify type of data like "%f" to print "x" variable that are float.
"x" is already a float so why we need to tell program again that we print a float variable.
It might look like a stupid question but i am curious the reason behind that.

```
   float x = 5.0;
   printf("%f",x);
```

Comment: Because the bit sequence `01000001` could be `A` or the integer value 65.  The bit sequence `11111111` could be 255 or -128.  It depends on how you interpret the bits, and you need to tell printf how to interpret them.

Comment: The reason is that `printf` does not intrinsically know the types of the arguments because  they are _variadic_ arguments. So it has to be told the types of the arguments. The format string also allows other characters to surround the variable output, for example: `printf("The value is %f units\n", x);`, and for the variable to be output in different formats, such as different minimum width, different precision, or different style.

Comment: Deep down the abstraction of types, 'x' (as a variable) is just some place in the memory. The contents of that position in memory have no special meaning, they're just a bunch of 0's and 10s. When we say that 'x' is of type 'float' what we are meaning is that the programmers have agreed to interpret the bunch of 0's and 1's as a floating point number, but it could have been anything. Thus you need to specify in printf how are you interpreting that value. If you pass another type, for example '%d', you may see that binary value interpreted as another type (an integer, in '%d' case).

Comment: You might want to look at how *variadic* functions are implemented to understand their limitations.

Comment: Try `printf("%d\n",x); printf("%p\n",x); printf("%llx\n",x);` and see for yourself how data has no intrinsic context on its own, especially in a low level language such as C.

Comment: @h0r53 - because your suggestion would invoke undefined behavior, the indications of doing it might look exactly normal.  With UB you cannot predict when or what it will do.

Answer (score 2):

> why do printf ... need to specify type of data (?)

`int printf(const char * restrict format, ...);` is a [*variadic* function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function#In_C).  `printf()` does not directly receive information past the `format` parameter about what else is passed nor their types.

`printf()` uses the `format` to know the count, location and type of the following `...` arguments.

---

There are various less well known alternatives to a *format* parameter. [e.g.](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/115143/29485)

Answer (score 1):

Information about the types of variables is known to the compiler at compile time, but it does not keep any of that information for the running program like some other languages do. At runtime, when the call to printf() is made, you must supply the type information that was lost in the compilation process.

Could they have written the compiler to use the compile-time information to compile different calls to printf()? Yes. But that would have made printf() different from all other functions, and "magical" in a way that users could not write for themselves. The way it's done now, you can write printf()-like functions yourself.

Answer (score 1):

It's a function of how variadic functions work in C.  The prototype for `printf` is

```
int printf( const char * restrict format, ... );
```

Only the first argument `format` is of a known, fixed type.  There is no fixed order or type for any additional arguments.  For example, if you write

```
printf( "%d %s %f\n", 1, "2", 3.14159 );
```

the compiler sets up the function call by evaluating the additional arguments and either pushing their results onto the stack or writing them to specific registers.  However, there's no way for the caller to communicate the number or types of additional arguments to `printf`.  There's nothing in the arguments themselves to indicate their type or how many there are.  `printf` just sees a sludge of bytes on the stack (or a bunch of argument registers), but it doesn't magically know how to pick specific items out of them.

That's why you need the conversion specifiers in the format string to tell `printf` what to expect.

Answer (score 0):

In other languages, it is resolved through **generics**, **inheritance**, or **polymorphism**

Generics would be something like `<genericType T> void print(T)` (I don't have any example)

As for inheritance, in Java, you have `System.out.println(Object)` function that **receives any type** (everything inherits `Object`)
And every `Object` has `toString` method that tells it what to print (how to represent)

And finally, polymorphism we see in C++
In which you can overload `<<` operator of `std::cout`
like `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Date& dt)`
In which case **linker/compiler chooses which of the methods** (with same name; criteria is/are types of arguments)

**C doesn't have** (intentionally) any of that stuff
Probably because it wants to stay "simple" (close, but not too close to assembly)

Comment: "C doesn't have (intentionally) any of that stuff" --> In C, limited code like `<genericType T> void print(T)` is possible via `_Generic`. `_Generic` also allows some inheritance.  Also used to realize a limited polymorphism.  See also `<tgmath.h>`